# Which regex tag to use in a Mechanize function?

Tags: regex, perl, mechanize

I retrieved all the links from the web page containing `/title/tt` inside the url in a list.

```
my @url_links= $mech->find_all_links( url_regex => qr/title\/tt/i );
```

but the list is too long so I want to filter by adding in the function find_all_Links that the link must be also in the tags starting with `<id="actor-tt...">` here is where the link (`/title/tt...`) is, in the code source retrieved by cmd.exe:

```html
<div class="filmo-row odd" id="actor-tt0361748">
<span class="year_column">
&nbsp;2009
</span>
<b><a href="/title/tt0361748/"
>Inglourious Basterds</a></b>
<br/>
Lt. Aldo Raine
</div>
```

I imagine you have to use a tag_regex but I don't know how because the command prompt doesn't seem to take tag_regex into account when I put it in.

Comment: What do you mean by command prompt? Are you running this on Windows as a one-liner? Put your code into a file and run it from there to avoid shell escapes.

Comment: Slightly on-topic and hillarious Perl Workshop video that relates to this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dFU-fL4dKUs

Answer (score 3):

Using [`HTML::TreeBuilder`](https://metacpan.org/pod/HTML::TreeBuilder) and [`HTML::Element`](https://metacpan.org/pod/HTML::Element) instead of `Mechanize`:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';
use HTML::TreeBuilder;

my $html_string = join "", <DATA>;

my $tree = HTML::TreeBuilder->new_from_content($html_string);

my @url_links = map { $_->attr_get_i("href") }
                map { $_->look_down(href => qr{/title/tt}) }
                $tree->look_down(id => qr/^actor-tt/);

say for @url_links;

__DATA__
<div class="filmo-row odd" id="actor-tt0361748">
    <span class="year_column">
      &nbsp;2009
    </span>
    <b><a href="/title/tt0361748/">Inglourious Basterds</a></b>
    <br/>
    Lt. Aldo Raine
</div>
<div id="not-the-right-id">
    <a href="/title/tt-looks-correct-but-wrong-id/"></a>
</div>
<div class="filmo-row odd" id="actor-tt0123456">
    <b><a href="/title/tt0123456/">Another movie</a></b>
</div>
<div class="filmo-row odd" id="actor-tt0123456">
    the id will match, but no href in here
</div>
```

`$tree->look_down(id => qr/^actor-tt/);` finds all elements whose `id` matches `actor-tt`. Then `$_->look_down(href => qr{/title/tt})` will find all elements within them with a field `href` matching `/title/tt`. Finally, `$_->attr_get_i("href")` returns the value of their `href` fields.

You might be interested in the method `new_from_url` or `new_from_file` from `HTML::TreeBuilder` rather than the `new_from_content` I used.

Answer (score 2):

WWW::Mechanize is not sophisticated enough to do what you're trying to do. It can only search links [on one criterium at a time](https://metacpan.org/release/WWW-Mechanize/source/lib/WWW/Mechanize.pm#L423), and it converts them to WWW::Mechanize::Link objects, which do not maintain their ancestry (as in position in the DOM tree).

Mechanize is meant to be a browser, not a scraper. It's important to pick the right tools for the job you have to do.

As [Dada suggested in their answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63410713/1331451), you can use your own parser to search for this. You can still extract the HTML out of WWW::Mechanize and then use the code they suggest. Use `$mech->content` or `$mech->content_raw` to get the HTML out.

---

There are several alternatives to this. While I personally like [Web::Scraper](https://metacpan.org/pod/Web::Scraper) for this kind of task, its interface is a bit weird and has a learning curve.

Instead, I would suggest using [Mojo::UserAgent](https://metacpan.org/pod/Mojo::UserAgent) and [Mojo::DOM](https://metacpan.org/pod/Mojo::DOM). In fact, the handy [ojo package](https://metacpan.org/pod/ojo) for one-liners should be able to do this.

```
perl -Mojo -E 'g("https://www.imdb.com/name/nm0000093/")->dom->find("div[id^=actor-tt] a")->map(sub {say $_->attr("href")})'
```

Broken down, this does the following:

- use Mojo::UserAgent to get that page
- look at the DOM tree
- find all `<a>`s inside `<div>`s that have an `id` that starts with *actor-tt* (see https://metacpan.org/pod/Mojo::DOM::CSS#SELECTORS for details)
- for each of them, print out the `href` attribute

You can customise this as much as you want.

---

Please note that according to their [Terms of Services](https://help.imdb.com/article/imdb/general-information/can-i-use-imdb-data-in-my-software/G5JTRESSHJBBHTGX?ref_=helpsrall#), scraping IMDB is not allowed.

Comment: You haven't finished your last sentence I think. I guess it used to be "See their Terms of Services" and then you rephrased it? Or maybe you wanted to add something? In doubt, I'll let you edit it yourself: you might have want to add a crucial piece of information.. "See how to become a billionaire without any efforts: <link>"? ;-)

Comment: @Dada I think I wanted to quote it and gave up. Watch the Sawyer X talk I linked on the question for more details about how I didn't try this code, or even wrote it, but if I had it would look like this.

Comment: Yeah I've watched it, pretty great :D I haven't seen much talks by Sawyer but he seems fun!